# Calculate CIDR from a given netmask - Java

Tags: java, ip, cidr, netmask

Is there a way to calculate a `CIDR`  given a `Sub net mask` using any `Java lib`/function/trick?? I have been looking for a while and all I can find is from  `CIDR -> Netmask` and I need it the other way arround  `Netmask -> CIDR` ... Im not that handy on `Java`, but im willing to read a lot =)  thnx guys

PzP =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whipped up a quick example. This converts an `InetAddress` into a cidr value, it also validates that the `InetAddress` represents a valid netmask.

The test input is `255.255.128.0`. The output cidr is `17`.

```
package com.stackoverflow._19531411;

import java.net.InetAddress;


public class NetmaskToCIDR {


    public static int convertNetmaskToCIDR(InetAddress netmask){

        byte[] netmaskBytes = netmask.getAddress();
        int cidr = 0;
        boolean zero = false;
        for(byte b : netmaskBytes){
            int mask = 0x80;

            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                int result = b & mask;
                if(result == 0){
                    zero = true;
                }else if(zero){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid netmask.");
                } else {
                    cidr++;
                }
                mask >>>= 1;
            }
        }
        return cidr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InetAddress netmask = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.128.0");

        System.out.println(convertNetmaskToCIDR(netmask));

    }
}
```

Credit for psuedocode @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090956/260633

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toCidrNotation` function in the [Apache SubnetUtils module](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) to do this. [Here's a Java example.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/jacoco/examples.cidr/SubnetUtilsExample.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Apache Net Jar (Class SubnetUtils) http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi

Also in a project that I was doing we used the excellent Postgres DB functions which also supported IPV6  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-net.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html